How to get Buttons Enabled? (logic issue?)
I currently have a program with some teams that are in pairs. Clicking on a team increases the Wins of the team being clicked, and increases the Losses of the pair it is linked to. A team with two losses is disabled and changes their text to "Eliminated".
I have a reset button that is supposed to clear all of the counters and, in theory, by clearing the counters the disabled buttons should be reenabled again. However, this is not the case, they stay disabled and their text switches back to the team name. How do I keep my buttons enabled after being reset?
Any input would be greatly appreciated :)


let groups = [{
    name: "Chaos Coordinators",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Sofa King Awesome",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Nerd Herd",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Laughing Stock",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Brainy Bunch Gone Wild",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Cereal Killers",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Mismatched Socks",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Awkward Turtles",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  }
];


// Create pairs from the groups
function makeMatches(array) {
  return array.map((_, i) => (i % 2 === 0) ? [array[i], array[i + 1]] : []).filter(v => v.length === 2);
}

let matches = makeMatches(groups);

// Create a map of team names to their index
const groupIndexMap = {};
groups.forEach((group, index) => {
  groupIndexMap[group.name] = index;
});

// Function to handle button clicks
function handleButtonClick(groupName) {
  const matchIndex = groupIndexMap[groupName];
  const match = matches.find(match => match.some(group => group.name === groupName));


  if (!match) return;

  match.forEach((group, button) => {
    if (group.name === groupName) {
      group.wins += 1;
    } else if (group.losses < 2) {
      group.losses += 1;
    }
  });

  updateButtonTexts();
  console.log(groups);
}

// Function to update button texts
function updateButtonTexts() {
  groups.forEach((group, index) => {
    const button = document.getElementById(`button${index + 1}`);
    if (button) {
      button.textContent = `${group.name} - Wins: ${group.wins} - Losses: ${group.losses}`;
    }
    if (group.losses == 2) {
      button.textContent = 'Eliminated';
      button.disabled = true;
    }
  });
}

// Function to reset all counters
function resetCounters() {
  groups.forEach(group => {
    group.wins = 0;
    group.losses = 0;
  });
  updateButtonTexts();
}


// Initialize button click handlers
function initializeButtons() {
  groups.forEach((group) => {
    const button = document.querySelector(`[data-team-name='${group.name}']`);
    if (button) {
      button.onclick = () => handleButtonClick(group.name);
    }
  });

  // Initialize reset button handler
  document.getElementById('resetButton').onclick = resetCounters;

  // Initial update of button texts
  updateButtonTexts();
}

// Initial render and setup
initializeButtons();
#group-buttons {
  position: relative;
  /* Container should be relative for positioning buttons absolutely */
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  /* Adjust height as needed */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.group-button {
  position: absolute;
  /* Allows for free positioning */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Indicates the element is clickable */
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Example styles for individual buttons */

#button1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button2 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}

#button3 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button4 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 200px;
}

#button5 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button6 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 200px;
}

#button7 {
  top: 350px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button8 {
  top: 350px;
  left: 200px;
}
<button id="resetButton">Reset All Counters</button>
<div id="group-buttons">
  <button id="button1" class="group-button" data-team-name="Chaos Coordinators">Chaos Coordinators - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button2" class="group-button" data-team-name="Sofa King Awesome">Sofa King Awesome - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button3" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Nerd Herd">The Nerd Herd - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button4" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Laughing Stock">The Laughing Stock - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button5" class="group-button" data-team-name="Brainy Bunch Gone Wild">Brainy Bunch Gone Wild - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button6" class="group-button" data-team-name="Cereal Killers">Cereal Killers - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button7" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Mismatched Socks">The Mismatched Socks - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button8" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Awkward Turtles">The Awkward Turtles - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
</div>




Seems to be working just fine in your snippet.

You never do button.disabled = false to re-enable the buttons when you reset the counters.

BTW, if (group.losses == 2) should be inside if (button). Otherwise you'll try to access properties of a button that doesn't exist.

Your title is very misleading. The counters are resetting, the problem is with enabling the button.

I wrote the title that way because I thought the counters were what was the issue :) (if the counters didn't reset then the button would stay disabled is what I gathered from watching the console because, if you look carefully, when you get to two losses on a button and reset then the two losses don't go away, which is what I thought might have been keeping it in that disabled state :)

my 2 cents... :)
Avoid duplicating information; like here with your list of HTML buttons and your array of JS objects containing your Teams [name, scores+/- ].
Prefer to generate one from the other.
I chose here to generate the sequence of HTML buttons from the array, following the data-driven principle; which allows me to add the btnUI property in connection with the button added on the user interface. See: Teams.forEach( team => // generate teams buttons...
then you will naturally need a function to update the value of the scores on the interface, here the function setButtonTeamScore( teamBtn, score_W, score_L )
Still in the spirit of avoiding duplication of information, I use here a CSS ::before on the label of the teams, which also allows to make a left justification and to align the scores on the right.
As for the distribution by pairs of teams it is done automatically since the available width allows to fit only 2 on each line.


const
  resetButton  = document.querySelector('#resetButton')
, groupButtons = document.querySelector('fieldset')
, Teams = 
    [ { name: 'Chaos Coordinators',     wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    , { name: 'Sofa King Awesome',      wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    , { name: 'The Nerd Herd',          wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    , { name: 'The Laughing Stock',     wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    , { name: 'Brainy Bunch Gone Wild', wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    , { name: 'Cereal Killers',         wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    , { name: 'The Mismatched Socks',   wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    , { name: 'The Awkward Turtles',    wins: 0, losses: 0 }
    ];

Teams.forEach( team =>  // generate teams buttons...
  {
  team.btnUI                  = document.createElement('button'); // add property 'btnUI' to retrieve UI his button
  team.btnUI.textContent      = 'Wins: 0 - Losses: 0';
  team.btnUI.dataset.teamName = team.name; // set data-team-name attribute
  groupButtons.append(team.btnUI);
  })

resetButton.addEventListener('click', () =>
  {
  Teams.forEach( team => 
    {
    team.wins   = 0;
    team.losses = 0;
    setButtonTeamScore( team.btnUI, 0, 0 ).classList.remove('noMoreClick');
    })
  });

groupButtons.addEventListener('click', evt => // change score... (event delegation method)
  {
  if (!evt.target.matches('button[data-team-name]')) return; // reject wrong places of click

  let 
    winIndx = Teams.findIndex( team => team.name === evt.target.dataset.teamName ) // determine which team is click-concern
  , looIndx = Boolean(winIndx %2) ? (winIndx -1) : (winIndx +1)                    // determine opponent team index
  , btn_W   = setButtonTeamScore( Teams[winIndx].btnUI, ++Teams[winIndx].wins, Teams[winIndx].losses )
  , btn_L   = setButtonTeamScore( Teams[looIndx].btnUI, Teams[looIndx].wins, --Teams[looIndx].losses )
    ;
  if (btn_L.disabled)
    btn_W.classList.add('noMoreClick');
  });

function setButtonTeamScore( teamBtn, score_W, score_L )
  {
  teamBtn.textContent = score_L <= -2 
                      ? 'Eliminated' 
                      : `Wins: ${score_W} - Losses: ${score_L}`;
                      
  teamBtn.disabled    = ( score_L <= -2 );
  
  return teamBtn;  // for chaining methods.
  }
#resetButton    { padding: .3rem .6rem; margin: .3rem; }
fieldset        { padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem; width: 39.5rem; }
fieldset button {
  width      : 18.7rem; 
  margin     : 0 1rem 1rem  0; 
  cursor     : pointer; 
  text-align : right;
  }
fieldset button::before {
  content     : attr(data-team-name) ' :';
  font-weight : bold;
  float       : inline-start;
  }
fieldset  button.noMoreClick { 
  pointer-events : none;
  cursor         : default;
  }
fieldset button.noMoreClick::before {
  background-color : gold;
  }
fieldset  button:disabled { 
  color  : red;
  cursor : not-allowed;
  }
<button id="resetButton">Reset All Counters</button>
<fieldset>
</fieldset>




Don't just post code. Explain what you did and why.

@Barmar done, I hope i didn't missing something important ?

Thank you for your answer :) (and your earlier edit of my question!) This is exactly what I was trying to do :) I was wondering however, because I started programming a little bit ago so I am still learning, what does the "for chaining methods" comment mean at the end of the code when you return teamBtn? and also you did not miss anything important, I fully understand your answer just so you know :)

@Jazzwal It is a big classic in JavaScript. Here the setButtonTeamScore() method returns a teamBtn object that corresponds to the team.btnUI argument that it received as input. Here this allows to directly chain on the return of this function a classlist() method, which is specific to this kind of object.

So, another 'method' can receive the 'teamBtn' object corresponding to the 'team.btnUI' argument before returning another 'teamBtn' object to be received by another 'method' and etc. etc. in a chain? (if I am understanding correctly)

@Jazzwal example : new Date().getFullYear().toString().substring(0,1)  does 3 chainings methods over the initial creation of a date element.

Oh okay I understand now, thank you :)

Use HTMLButtonElement's disabled property, set to a boolean value.

The code seems a bit too complicated and there are some non-addressed issues:

instead of creating an Array with pairs, use a different strategy: linked (graph) nodes. Clone the data, then each team Object should have an opponent property pointing to the opposing team Object, and vice-versa — by using: team.opponent = teams[i + (i % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1)]; or if you like: team.opponent = teams[i + 1 - i % 2 * 2];
disable both buttons, not only the one of the losing party.
create a structuredClone to not pollute the original data - this way you don't need to do heavy resets - just reuse the original initial data.
prepopulated HTML is not necessary, create the buttons dynamically!

Simplified example:


// Data
const groups = [ {name: "Chaos Coordinators", wins: 0, losses: 0}, {name: "Sofa King Awesome", wins: 0, losses: 0}, {name: "The Nerd Herd", wins: 0, losses: 0}, {name: "The Laughing Stock", wins: 0, losses: 0}, {name: "Brainy Bunch Gone Wild", wins: 0, losses: 0}, {name: "Cereal Killers", wins: 0, losses: 0}, {name: "The Mismatched Socks", wins: 0, losses: 0}, {name: "The Awkward Turtles", wins: 0, losses: 0}];

// DOM helpers 
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// App
const max = 2; // Max losses. SET AS DESIRED
const elGroupButtons = el("#group-buttons");

const updateButton = (team) => {
  const text = team.losses === max ? "Eliminated" : `Wins: ${team.wins} - Losses: ${team.losses}`;
  team.button.textContent = `${team.name} - ${text}`;
  team.button.disabled = team.losses === max || team.opponent.losses === max;
  team.button.classList.toggle("is-eliminated", team.losses === max);
};

const updateScore = (team, score = 1) => {
  team.wins += score;
  team.opponent.losses += score;
  updateButton(team);
  updateButton(team.opponent);
};

const makeMatches = (array) => {
  elGroupButtons.innerHTML = ""; // Cleanup
  // Let's clone data and recreate the buttons
  structuredClone(array).forEach((team, i, teams) => {
    team.opponent = teams[i + (i % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1)];
    team.button = elNew("button", {
      className: "group-button",
      onclick() { updateScore(team); }
    });
    updateButton(team); // Initial button text
    elGroupButtons.append(team.button);
  });
};

// Init and Reset event
const matches = makeMatches(groups);
el("#resetButton").addEventListener("click", () => makeMatches(groups));
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

#group-buttons {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
  gap: 0.5em;
  
  & .group-button {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.3em);
    padding: 1em;

    &.is-eliminated {
      color: #f008;
    }
  }
}
<button id="resetButton">RESET</button>
<div id="group-buttons"></div>




Thank you so much for the informative answer :), I am trying to figure out the backend for making a tournament bracket, so I think the structuredClone() is exactly what I am looking for to move between rounds of a tournament without messing up the arrays from previous rounds as eliminations occur :)

@Jazzwal you're welcome. Yes, depending on the use case, but keeping the original data intact is always a good practice. Also having independently working function like updateScore(team, score) and updateButton(team) allows you for more flexibility in the future - just for example say you load upfront some incomplete matches data where teams already have some score associated - and you're covered for those cases too. No need to write extra JS code.

You need to set button.disabled = true; when the losses is less than 2. This will re-enable the button when you reset the counters.
function updateButtonTexts() {
  groups.forEach((group, index) => {
    const button = document.getElementById(`button${index + 1}`);
    if (button) {
      button.textContent = `${group.name} - Wins: ${group.wins} - Losses: ${group.losses}`;
      if (group.losses == 2) {
        button.textContent = 'Eliminated';
        button.disabled = true;
      } else {
        button.disabled = false;
      }
    }
  });
}



let groups = [{
    name: "Chaos Coordinators",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Sofa King Awesome",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Nerd Herd",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Laughing Stock",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Brainy Bunch Gone Wild",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "Cereal Killers",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Mismatched Socks",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  },
  {
    name: "The Awkward Turtles",
    wins: 0,
    losses: 0
  }
];


// Create pairs from the groups
function makeMatches(array) {
  return array.map((_, i) => (i % 2 === 0) ? [array[i], array[i + 1]] : []).filter(v => v.length === 2);
}

let matches = makeMatches(groups);

// Create a map of team names to their index
const groupIndexMap = {};
groups.forEach((group, index) => {
  groupIndexMap[group.name] = index;
});

// Function to handle button clicks
function handleButtonClick(groupName) {
  const matchIndex = groupIndexMap[groupName];
  const match = matches.find(match => match.some(group => group.name === groupName));


  if (!match) return;

  match.forEach((group, button) => {
    if (group.name === groupName) {
      group.wins += 1;
    } else if (group.losses < 2) {
      group.losses += 1;
    }
  });

  updateButtonTexts();
  //console.log(groups);
}

// Function to update button texts
function updateButtonTexts() {
  groups.forEach((group, index) => {
    const button = document.getElementById(`button${index + 1}`);
    if (button) {
      button.textContent = `${group.name} - Wins: ${group.wins} - Losses: ${group.losses}`;
      if (group.losses == 2) {
        button.textContent = 'Eliminated';
        button.disabled = true;
      } else {
        button.disabled = false;
      }
    }
  });
}

// Function to reset all counters
function resetCounters() {
  groups.forEach(group => {
    group.wins = 0;
    group.losses = 0;
  });
  updateButtonTexts();
}


// Initialize button click handlers
function initializeButtons() {
  groups.forEach((group) => {
    const button = document.querySelector(`[data-team-name='${group.name}']`);
    if (button) {
      button.onclick = () => handleButtonClick(group.name);
    }
  });

  // Initialize reset button handler
  document.getElementById('resetButton').onclick = resetCounters;

  // Initial update of button texts
  updateButtonTexts();
}

// Initial render and setup
initializeButtons();
#group-buttons {
  position: relative;
  /* Container should be relative for positioning buttons absolutely */
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  /* Adjust height as needed */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.group-button {
  position: absolute;
  /* Allows for free positioning */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Indicates the element is clickable */
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Example styles for individual buttons */

#button1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button2 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}

#button3 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button4 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 200px;
}

#button5 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button6 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 200px;
}

#button7 {
  top: 350px;
  left: 50px;
}

#button8 {
  top: 350px;
  left: 200px;
}
<button id="resetButton">Reset All Counters</button>
<div id="group-buttons">
  <button id="button1" class="group-button" data-team-name="Chaos Coordinators">Chaos Coordinators - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button2" class="group-button" data-team-name="Sofa King Awesome">Sofa King Awesome - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button3" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Nerd Herd">The Nerd Herd - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button4" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Laughing Stock">The Laughing Stock - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button5" class="group-button" data-team-name="Brainy Bunch Gone Wild">Brainy Bunch Gone Wild - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button6" class="group-button" data-team-name="Cereal Killers">Cereal Killers - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button7" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Mismatched Socks">The Mismatched Socks - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
  <button id="button8" class="group-button" data-team-name="The Awkward Turtles">The Awkward Turtles - Wins: 0 - Losses: 0</button>
</div>




I tried that, but the button is still disabled after hitting the reset button :)

i'm assuming its because the counter didn't reset :)

I had a typo, disable should be disabled.

Why would you assume that? You display the counters in the button text.

I hypothesized that from watching the console :)

the counters don't start counting from zero until after you press a button, so I thought they would not become re-enabled until after they were pressed - which they couldn't cuz they were disabled
